# Delphi class procedure overload

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

Consider this code :

```
  TForm3 = class(TForm)
  public
   class procedure GetAConn(var res:String); overload;
   class procedure GetAConn(var res:Integer);overload;
    { Public declarations }
  end;

class procedure TForm3.GetAConn(var res: String);
begin
 showmessage(res);
end;

class procedure TForm3.GetAConn(var res: Integer);
begin
 showmessage(IntToStr(res))
end;
```

which compiles without any problems.

Now, If I'm doing this :

```
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
 TForm3.GetAConn('aaa');
 TForm3.GetAConn(10);
end;
```

I get [DCC Error] Unit3.pas(64): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'GetAConn' that can be called with these arguments.

I didn't find something about this being restricted in Delphi XE.

LE: is working in this way:

```
class procedure TForm3.GetAConn(var res: String);
begin
 res := res + 'modif';
end;

class procedure TForm3.GetAConn(var res: Integer);
begin
 res := res + 100;
end;
procedure TForm3.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var s:String;
    i:Integer;
begin
 s:='aaa';
 TForm3.GetAConn(s);
 showmessage(s);
 i:=10;
 TForm3.GetAConn(i);
 showmessage(IntToStr(i))
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're passing the parameters [by reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_by_reference#Call_by_reference). Drop the `var` and all should be well:

```
class procedure GetAConn(const res: String); overload;
class procedure GetAConn(res: Integer); overload;
```

(As you don't modify the string parameter I suggest passing it as `const`.)

If you indeed need reference parameters than you can't pass literals or constants, of course. But that has nothing to do with using `overload`. (Besides the fact that overloading obsfuscates the error message.)

Comment: +1 for the answer.If I need to pass the params by reference it would not work?

Comment: The Integer isn't modified either. May as well pass it as `const` too.

Comment: @David: That's true but passing const Integers isn't Delphi idiomatic. Maybe it's time to change that idiom. :-)

Comment: The main reason you prefer it for `strings` is to avoid the overhead associated with by value passing of managed types. It's a shame that particular performance consideration gets conflated with parameter semantics.

Comment: it's logic. It seems that I need to get some sleep. Thanks all.